# Botões com imagens dinâmicos com kivy

Tags: python, imagem, button, kivy

### Problema

Tenho um botão com imagem circular, com a imagem na proporção 1:1, e ao executar o código (abaixo) o programa gera uma tela com proporção também de 1:1, mas é possível redimensionar a tela e alterar sua proporção e tamanho, porém, a imagem não cresce junto como a tela e ocupa um espaço proporcional menor. Tentei definir valores para o `size_hint:`, porém ele distorce a imagem, menos em uma única proporção. Como posso tornar esse botão adaptável em relação a qualquer proporção e tamanho, sem distorções e com o mesmo espaço proporcional?

#### Tela gerada (1:1)

[image: Tela gerada]

#### Tela redimensionada (16:9)

[image: Tela redimensionada]

### Código

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class FloatingApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return FloatLayout()

flApp = FloatingApp()

flApp.run()
```

### Arquivo .kv

```
<Botao@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size: 138, 138
    background_normal: 'bd.png'
    background_down: 'bd1.png'
    background_color: 0.88, 0.88, 0.88, 1  
    size_hint: None, None

<FloatLayout>:
    Botao:

        text:"Botao"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
```

Comment: para a imagem se adaptar ao tamanho pode usar a propriedade `size_hint`

Comment: Sim, mas nesse caso, ele se adapta ao tamanho da tela, e distorce a imagem. o objetivo é conseguir se adaptar, sem distorcoes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos definir a largura com o size_hint e a altura fica igual.

```
size_hint: 0.1, None
height: self.width
```

Comment: Explique o que você fez